# Javascript Array dont print empty value

Tags: javascript

I have this code below with 3 arrays and sometime the green array will be completely `empty` how do i make it so that when i combine all my arrays and loop through my foreach it doesn't print undefined value? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var blue = job['blue-color'];
var red = job['red-color'];
var green = job['green-color']; 
var colors = blue .concat(red,green);


var colorbooks = '<div">';
$.each(colors, function (index) {
  colorbooks += '<div">' + colors[index] + '</div>';
});
colorbooks+= '</div>';
```

Comment: can you show job ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just check if your value is *truthy* before printing it :

```
var blue = job['blue-color'] || [];
var red = job['red-color'] || [];
var green = job['green-color'] || [];
var colors = blue.concat(red, green);


var colorbooks = '<div">';
$.each(colors, function(index) {
                            //If it's undefined, it will print an empty String instead
  colorbooks += '<div">' + (colors[index] || '') + '</div>';
});
colorbooks += '</div>';
```

As *@Margon* advised in the comments, if `job['XXX-color']` is undefined, you can also assign an empty array to your variable instead : `var blue = job['blue-color'] || [];`

Comment: May I suggest to also check also "job['X-color']" is different from undefined? Like you did in your (colors[index] || '') 

So it become (job['green-color'] || []) and so on..

Comment: @Zenoo is there no way to make it print nothing instead?

Comment: @Bobby That's exactly what that does.

Answer (score 0):

You can first use `filter()` to get the defined values only and then use `forEach()` to `console.log` all those values:

```js
var blue = [''];
var red = ['red1'];
var green = ['', 'blue1']
var colors = blue .concat(red,green);
console.log(colors);
colors.filter(item => item).forEach(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

**This might help**

```
<script>

var a = [''];
var b= ['red1'];
var v = ['', 'blue1']
var colors = v .concat(a,b);
$.each(colors,function(index,value){
alert(value);
});

</script>
```